# Airflow customizing logs

Tags: logging, airflow

I want to customize my airflow logs(dag log, scheduler log) and load them to ElasticSearch
(I'm not using external logging because I'm using Fluentd for my entire logs)

Since airflow logging uses python logging, I have no idea how can I write my logs with other information (such as owner, task_id ..)

Is there any way to write my logs with those(owner, task_id, dag_id) information?

I have searched Airflow Documents, but got no idea

Answer (score 1):

Airflow has Elasticsearch provider and it has task logging capability - you can see this in the documentation: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-elasticsearch/stable/logging/index.html

It has some configurability built in (see the docs) so you can check if this is enough for you. If not, you are free to extend the handler yourself or write a new handler based on the code of the Elasticsearch handler and configure it in your Airflow instance. Airflow is really extendable platform and custom Python classes are the first-class-citizens in Airflow if you need to customize it.